# FullCalendar Events: Confused how to enable resizing

Tags: javascript, jquery, fullcalendar

I'm using the FullCalendar plugin, and am very pleased with it, however I can't figure out how to enable resizing.  I looked at the source of the calendar on the main FullCalendar page, and my code is no different save that I get my events from a source rather than explicitly define them.

What am I missing?

```
$('#schedule').fullCalendar({
                                events: '/campaigns/scheduled',
                                editable: true
                              });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

did you include the jquery ui core + resizables?
http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_ui/Requirements/